# Does Coldfusion10 come with the cfcompile utility and if so where is it located?

Tags: coldfusion, compilation

According to the documentation it's supposed to be in the root folder but when I search my entire hard drive for "cfcompile" nothing comes up. When I run cfcompile from the command prompt it also doesn't work.

Can someone tell me if the free version of ColdFusion10 comes with cfcompile and if so exactly how to access it?

Comment: In previous versions it used to be in the /bin/ folder as a batch file (on windows).  I can't find it on my CF10 developer installation, but cfcompile is in the CF 10 docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the bug database, it is *not* included in ColdFusion 10. It is currently listed as an open/tofix, so feel free to vote for it: [bug #3197628](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3197628).

( I am guessing it is related to the switch to Tomcat, as the old `cfcompile.bat` file referenced `jrun.jar`, which is no longer included either for obvious reasons. )

Answer (score 2):

CFCompile issue is fixed in CF10.

### Please follow the below steps to compile files to bytecode.

Step 1: GO to  the folder C:\Development\Servers\ColdFusion\cfusion\bin

### Syntax

cfcompile -deploy

### Example

cfcompile -deploy C:\Development\Servers\ColdFusion\cfusion\wwwroot C:\FilesToCompile C:\compiledFiles

Comment: According to the bug report "This is fixed in ColdFusion 10 update 1."